# Rejecting in beforeRemote, can I use res.send or have to use next()?

Tags: express, loopbackjs

TL;DR 
What are the potential problems/downsides of not calling next() in a beforeRemote, assuming the client response is managed in other ways

Hi.

I have a base validation function in a model beforeRemote hook which needs to return an rejection to the client if certain conditions are/not meet.

I'm using res.send in an earlier route interception which works perfectly and res.send in the beforeRemote also seems to work. But I'm worried about the documentation stating very clearly that "next" must be called which means that I cannot res.send manually.

How I do it in the earlier route

```
res.statusCode = 401;
return res.send("Access denied");
```

How I play it safe

```
err = new Error("Access Denied");
err.status = 401;
delete err.stack;
return next(err);
```

I prefer the first method, as I don't have to spend "time" throwing an error and removing the stacktrace (needed in other places, so cannot be globally removed) before calling back. The res.send just seems cleaner to me, but that might be a misconception?
In the end I'm unsure if there is any long terms drawback on not ending the remote "in Loopback context" ((ctx.)res.send is "just" Express).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second method is more flexible. It allows you to perform some action before sending the reply. For instance, you may want to log all denied request. Or maybe redirect to home no matter where the error was generated.

Using `next(err)` all you have to do is add some middleware for doing that, while with your first method it would most likely require duplicate code in lots of places. Or, ultimately to avoid that, write something that does just what `next` enables you to do already.

Comment: True. Passing next the "correct" way would allow for some additional handling, where are res.send would be ending the chain. But in this case, it is exactly what I want, it is a basic rejection/requirement and I don't imaging any need to do anything more than just rejecting the client.

Comment: So the core of the question remains: What is the potential problems/downsides of not calling next() in a beforeRemote

Comment: I was going to say there isn't any in your case, you're just ending the request/response cycle early. However there might be one downside. Since you're not calling next, I am pretty sure you won't be able to debug your server properly using [debug strings](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Setting+debug+strings) for strong-remoting.

Comment: I can live with that answer and agree that is would at the very least prevent the loopback-debug as you are ending it outside of it's scope, so it would see the remote as stalled. I'm still concerned that there is more to that then just the debug not working, as you are effectively killing the middelware chain by returning the Express res.send and not the Loopback next().

Comment: All the middlewares used by your server are listed inside the server/middlewares.json (with default scaffolding). I believe they are executed in the order they are defined inside the file (to confirm). Knowing that, you can at least identify exactly which middlewares are being short-circuited by your early response. But there may be other parts of the loopback app that may be affected, I don't know. Maybe performance profiling might be affected too